# apache runs on a different version then shown and shows/uses a wrong version of php

Tags: php, apache2, raspbian

I am having a strange problem with PHP on a raspberry Pi lately.
It occurred as i tried to run the "password_hash" function and wonderd why it didn't work. The script didn't even throw an error or something, it just didn't continue.

The specs first:

- PC = Raspberry Pi I
- OS = Raspbian
- Installed Apache Version = 2.4.12
- Installed PHP Version = 5.6.15

All these specs are coming from the console.

So it turned out, that the PHP version used by apache is different from the one i got from the console. Installed is PHP 5.6.15 but used is (acording to phpinfo() ) PHP 5.4.45. The php.ini is correctly located.
The more weird part is, that the apache version (also acording to phpinfo() ) seems to be Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) and i can't figure out why.

So intuitive i removed and reinstalled php and apache, checked the versions in the console, where it was correct (again), run another script with only phpinfo() and got the same sobering results. I also tried to install it manualy. And to get this out of the way, i did not upgrade the PHP version, it was a clean install on a clean, recently installed OS.

Had any of you ever run into something similar and knows a way to fixed it?

Comment: did you restart apache after your install ?

Comment: multiple times, because i thought something went wrong, the first time

Comment: This question is better suited for http://serverfault.com/, try over there and remove it here

Comment: Side note you can run the compatability pack to use `password_hash` on older versions of php (https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/)

Comment: Thanks. I will tried it over there.
I know, i also know that the password_hash function is just an more reliable and enhanced way of crypt and that you can do basicly the same, but i wanna use php5.6 for different reasons :)